# Calculating Time Difference, 60 Minute countdown

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey I have to calculate amount of minutes remaining out of 60 minutes from a timestamp such as:

```
2017-08-01T00:18:38.000-04:00
```

So according to this time stamp, if it becamse 0:18:39.000 I would have 59 Minutes remaining.

The thing I have tried is:

```
              let time = timeToDisplay.valueOf();
              let date = new Date();
              let timeDiff = new Date(date.valueOf() - time);
              //If Client date is ahead of TBT DATE
              if (date.valueOf() < time) {
                //IF DATE IS ONLY 1 or 0 DAYS APART | For Midnight Switch
                if (date.getDate() - timeToDisplay.getDate() <= 1) {
                  if (timeDiff.getMinutes() <= 60) {
                    this.timeDisplayed = (60 - timeDiff.getMinutes()).toString();
}
```

This is not correct as it works during certain times of the day, the timestamp can change, but it always has to calculate time remaining of the 60 minutes.

Comment: You're over thinking it. Time runs in 1 direction so subtract the timestamp from now and divide by 60 * 1000 (JS stores timestamps in milliseconds).

Comment: Ok cool, ill try that and see if its the correct solution. I realized i was over thinking it a bit haha